# Turn LDAP tracing on WebSphere 7?

Tags: ldap, websphere, novell

I am having difficulty logging into our test environment, but not production.

I confirmed in the WebSphere Admin console that our LDAP configuration is the same as production. Nothing has changed on the configuration end.

Does anyone know the steps to turn on LDAP tracing? I want to log the connection the WebSphere Application Server (WAS) is making with our Novell eDirectory Server (LDAP).

Server OS   Linux 2.6.18-371.12.1.el5
App Server  IBM WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.15
Server DB   Oracle 11.2

Answer (score 2):

This is old and probably resolved but here is the info for turning on trace for security. This is taken from the manually gathering of the [mustgather](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21470063#show-hide) for websphere security issues...

1. In the administrative console, navigate to TroubleShooting > Logs and Trace > server_name.
2. Select Diagnostic Trace Service. Set the Maximum Number of Historical Files to 20.
3. Click Apply, then select Change Log Detail Levels.
4. On the Configuration tab, clear the trace specification in the box and replace it with the following trace specification:

   ```
   *=info:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.security.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.wim.*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.wim.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wim.*=all
   ```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I forgot what I had done but the trace would have been helpful.